# Conditional filtering in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Can I use one of the $and filters conditionally, ie. when some condition is met I would like to use the filter otherwise do not use filter:

```
Collection.find({
  $and: [
    { date  },
    { room: [isConditionMet] ? room : [do not use room filter at all] },
  ]
}
```

Is it possible on mongo query level?

Comment: Yes it's possible with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the same as using $or?

```
Collection.find({
  $and: [
    { date: ...  },
    { $or: [
      {isConditionNOTmet},
      {room: ... }
    ]}
  ]
})
```

Comment: Do you have to enclose the document by `$expr:{ ... }`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. No, although `isConditionNOTmet` may require it, depending on the logic.

Comment: I tried { $or: [ { isDoubleRoom }, { room }]} in order to get logic like that: if `isDoubleRoom` is true then use filter isDoubleRoom, if `isDoubleRoom` is false then use `room` filter, but it doesn't work. Can you help me understand that?